# Причина возникновения конфликта слияния

Tags: git, git-merge

Насколько мне известно, конфликт возникает, если одна и та же строка изменяется различным образом в двух разных ветках. В моём случае конфликт возникает со строки 5, но эта строка идентична в обеих версиях файла.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

можно это воспроизвести, например, так:

```
$ git init
$ echo 1 > file
$ git add file
$ git commit -m 1
$ git checkout -b new
$ echo 2 >> file
$ git commit -am 2
$ git checkout master
$ truncate -s -1 file
$ git commit -am 3
$ git merge new
$ cat file
<<<<<<< HEAD
1
=======
1
2
>>>>>>> new
```

суть в том, что в ветке master я убрал в конце файла символ новой строки, а в ветке new добавил строку.

теперь при попытке слияния получаю идентичную вашей картину.

---

значит, и у вас строки **не** идентичны. теоретически можно воспроизвести аналогичную картину и с помощью вариаций символов, которыми могут [разделяться строки в различных операционных системах](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8).

Answer (score 0):

git (в отличии от svn) не пытается быть умнее пользователя и выдает конфликт если просто файл менялся в обеих ветках.

Если в одной ветке была добавлена строки, и в другой была добавлена такая же строка в том же месте, то не факт что после слияния файл должен быть таким же как в обеих ветках. Вполне вероятно что после слияния должны быть обе копии строки.

Comment: *Вполне вероятно что после слияния должны быть обе копии строки.* — пробовал воспроизвести. увы, не вышло. хотя конфликт и наличествует, но добавленная строка не фигурирует между `<<<<<<<` и `=======`